# How do I ask about availability of a certain class of software on Linux?

Tags: discussion

**Generic part**:

I would like to learn about the applications that exist in a certain class of software on Linux. How do I best ask a question about that on *Software Recommendations* in a way that will follow the rules of the site and be useful and informative for others in the long term?

**Specific part**:

I would like to learn about drawing and painting software that is available on Linux, or may become available soon (I believe there isn't much today; is there any hope for the better?). I'd like to use Ubuntu on [Microsoft Surface Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface_Pro_2) line of tablet/laptops and draw on it.

This class of software I have in mind includes tools such as:

- [Adobe_Photoshop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop)
- [Paint Tool SAI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAI_%28software%29)
- [Manga Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manga_Studio)

All of which are not available on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Try to ask a question only when you know what you're looking for. A good question would ask for a software running on Linux that has a given feature or set of features, not "a Linux equivalent to Adobe Photoshop".

You may perfectly well ask for "a software to draw on Linux", but I would recommend describing what you mean by drawing on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Basically just use your specifics part with a few adjustments:

- *list **detailed*** feature requirements (Make it explicit and detailed - better to be over specific and get a couple good answers that miss one or two features than too broad and have 40 possible answers)
- You don't need to list what you would be using in Windows environment (you still can but you don't need to and it is only sometimes helpful)